# How to get all pages from webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to get list of all shoes from all the pages from this website https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/all-mens-footwear but i dont know what else to write in my code.
Basically i would like to select a brand name shoes from all the pages from the website. For example i would like to select New Balance shoes and i would like to print a list of all shoes by the name branc i selected. Here is my code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
Url = 'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/all-mens-footwear'
uClient = uReq(Url)
Page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(Page, "html.parser")
for i in page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"rs-facet-name-container"}):
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is updating its element using js script so you won't be able to use beautifulsoup alone you have to use automation.

This below code won't work because the element gets updated after few milliseconds. It will initally show all the brands then it will update and show the chosen brand so use automation.

**Code that fails:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
Url = 'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/all-mens-footwear'
url_st = 'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/mens-athletic-shoes?pageNumber=0&filterFacets=X_BRAND'

for idx, br in enumerate(brands_name):
    if idx==0:
        url_st += '%3A'+ '%20'.join(br.split(' '))
    else: 
        url_st += '%2C' + '%20'.join(br.split(' '))

uClient = uReq(url_st)
time.sleep(4)
Page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(Page, "html.parser") 
for match in page_soup.find_all('div', class_='rs_product_description d-block'):
    print(match.text)
```

**Code: (selenium + bs4)**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())#, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

brands_name = ['New Balance']

filter_facet ='filterFacets=X_BRAND'
for idx, br in enumerate(brands_name):
    if idx==0:
        filter_facet += '%3A'+ '%20'.join(br.split(' '))
    else: 
        filter_facet += '%2C' + '%20'.join(br.split(' '))

url = f"https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/mens-athletic-shoes?pageNumber=0&{filter_facet}"        
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')  
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('close')
if elem:
    elem.click()
for match in page_soup.find_all('div', class_='rs_product_description d-block'):
    print(match.text)
    
page_num = page_soup.find_all('a', class_='rs-page-item')
pnum = [int(pn.text) for pn in page_num if pn.text!='']
if len(pnum)>=2:
    for pn in range(1, len(pnum)):
        url = f"https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/mens-athletic-shoes?pageNumber={pn}&{filter_facet}"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser") 
        for match in page_soup.find_all('div', class_='rs_product_description d-block'):
            print(match.text)
```

---

```
New Balance Men's 410v6 Trail Running Shoes
New Balance Men's 623v3 Training Shoes
.
.
.
New Balance Men's Fresh Foam Beacon Running Shoes
New Balance Men's Fresh Foam Cruz v2 SockFit Running Shoes
New Balance Men's 470 Running Shoes
New Balance Men's 996v3 Tennis Shoes
New Balance Men's 1260 V7 Running Shoes
New Balance Men's Fresh Foam Beacon Running Shoes
```

I have commented out headerless chrome because when you open it you will get a dialog button after closing it you can fetch the products details. In browserless automation you won't be able to do it( Can't answer this. not so good with selenium concepts)

Don't forget to install:  `webdriver_manager`
using `pip install webdriver_manager`

Comment: If this answer helps, please don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on tick. If not, Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on filter button and check all the brand you want.
You just have to do the `driver.find element by  xpath()`
If you use selenium you must know this.

Comment: im using beautiful soup

Answer (score 0):

The page is creating the links that you want using java script, you can not scrape that, you need to replicate the page requests, in this case the page is sending a post request:

```
Request URL: https://prod-catalog-product-api.dickssportinggoods.com/v1/search
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [2600:1400:d:696::25db]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

check the requests headers with inspect element tools from the browser to emulate the post request

This is the url where the post requests is being sent:

```
https://prod-catalog-product-api.dickssportinggoods.com/v1/search
```

and this is the post info the browser is sending

```
{selectedCategory: "12301_1714863", selectedStore: "1406", selectedSort: 1,…}
isFamilyPage: true
pageNumber: 0
pageSize: 48
searchTypes: []
selectedCategory: "12301_1714863"
selectedFilters: {X_BRAND: ["New Balance"]}   #<--- this is the info that you want to get
selectedSort: 1
selectedStore: "1406"
storeId: 15108
totalCount: 3360
```

The page might also require headers, so make sure to emulate the requests sent by the browser.